# How to add a list to a list of lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm coding a sudoku puzzle solver and I want to create a 9x9 grid where every cell is a list of it's own. The list sudokuGrid is the unsolved puzzle. It's a 2d list only. The list availableNumbers should be a 3d list where every empty cell (represented with a 0 in sudokuGrid) should have a list with the numbers 1-9. 
How do I add the list?

```py
sudokuGrid = []
sudokuGrid.append([0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0])
sudokuGrid.append([0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
sudokuGrid.append([3, 4, 0, 5, 9, 0, 0, 0, 7])
sudokuGrid.append([6, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0])
sudokuGrid.append([0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0])
sudokuGrid.append([0, 0, 4, 8, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0])
sudokuGrid.append([0, 0, 6, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 5])
sudokuGrid.append([0, 5, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0])
sudokuGrid.append([0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 9, 0])

availableNumbers = []

for i in range (9):
    for j in range(9):
        if sudokuGrid[i][j] == 0:
            availableNumbers[i][j][k] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
        else:
            availableNumbers[i][j][k] = sudokuGrid[i][j]
            break
```

I get an error saying list index is out of range.

Comment: Where does `k` come from? Also, these assignments turn the list of lists to a list of lists of lists

Comment: `availableNumbers ` starts off empty, so even `availableNumbers[0]` is an index out of range.

Comment: `availableNumbers` is an empty list so when you try to access the i'th element it does not exist.

Comment: "Every cell is a list of it's own" - To accomplish this, why not use a dictionary where your key is a tuple `(i, j)` and value will be your list `availableNumbers`? In other words, I suggest getting rid of `k` altogether to make the implementation simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize your `availableNumbers` list to have the same dimensions that you are trying to index to in order to add the values. You're getting an index error because `availableNumbers[i][j][k]` does not exist on an empty list. Also, you do not have `k` defined as anything. There's an easier way to do this without needing to initialize empty lists. Just use the `copy` module and make a copy of your `sudokuGrid` and replace all the `0` elements with a list of their potential values.

```
import copy
sudokuGrid = []
sudokuGrid.append([0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0])
sudokuGrid.append([0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
sudokuGrid.append([3, 4, 0, 5, 9, 0, 0, 0, 7])
sudokuGrid.append([6, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0])
sudokuGrid.append([0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0])
sudokuGrid.append([0, 0, 4, 8, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0])
sudokuGrid.append([0, 0, 6, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 5])
sudokuGrid.append([0, 5, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0])
sudokuGrid.append([0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 9, 0])

availableNumbers = copy.deepcopy(sudokuGrid)

for i in range(0, len(availableNumbers)):
    for x in range(0, len(availableNumbers[i])):
        if availableNumbers[i][x] == 0:
            availableNumbers[i][x] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

print(availableNumbers)
```

output:

```
[[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 8, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 1, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]],
 [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 9, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]], 
 [3, 4, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 5, 9, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 7], 
 [6, 8, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 4, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]], 
 [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 7, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]], 
 [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 4, 8, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 1, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]], 
 [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 6, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 8, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 5], 
 [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 5, 1, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 2, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]],
 [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 2, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 9, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]]
```

Comment: I'll take that back. Can't use if len(availableNumbers[i][j]) == 1: Doesn't work. It says "Expected type 'Sized', got int instead" I'll use Hoog's solution instead! :)

Comment: that's because you have mixed integers and lists for availableNumbers[i][j] so integers don't have length. Also, I just ran his solution with the `if len(availableNumbers[i][j]) == 1` and you get `TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()`

Comment: you should be using `if isinstance(availableNumbers[i][j], int):`

Answer (score 1):

A few small changes will let you build up `availablenumbers` as you go:

```
sudokuGrid = []
sudokuGrid.append([0, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0])
sudokuGrid.append([0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
sudokuGrid.append([3, 4, 0, 5, 9, 0, 0, 0, 7])
sudokuGrid.append([6, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0])
sudokuGrid.append([0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0, 0, 0])
sudokuGrid.append([0, 0, 4, 8, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0])
sudokuGrid.append([0, 0, 6, 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 5])
sudokuGrid.append([0, 5, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0])
sudokuGrid.append([0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 9, 0])

availableNumbers = []

for i in range (9):
    availableNumbers.append([])
    for j in range(9):
        availableNumbers[i].append([])
        if sudokuGrid[i][j] == 0:
            availableNumbers[i][j] = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
        else:
            availableNumbers[i][j] = sudokuGrid[i][j]

for a in availableNumbers:
    print(a)
```

By appending to `availableNumbers` or `availableNumbers[i]` at the start of each loop we ensure that there is some space in `availableNumbers` where we can store our variables.  That, along with removing your `break` statement and removing whatever `k` was will get you the following (line by line) output:

```
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 8, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 1, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 9, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
[3, 4, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 5, 9, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 7]
[6, 8, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 4, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 7, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 4, 8, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 1, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 6, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 8, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 5]
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 5, 1, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 2, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 2, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], 9, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]]
```

Comment: Thank you! That was even better! I couldn't figure out how to deal with the cells that weren't empty! How to remove all numbers but the one in the cell. Now that happens automatically